# Defining the directory to save outputs in Python for text files

Tags: python, text, directory

I would like to save my outputs (which are text files) from a Python script to a different directory. Following is my code to define the directory for my  outputs:

```
headers = list(uniq)
output_headers = open(save_path, "headers_dash1" + "_" + str(count) + ".raw", "w")
for item in headers:
    output_headers.write("%s\n" % item)
```

How can I generate these outputs to a different fixed directory like:
D:\Test\"The file name"

Comment: do you want to write headers in a different file everytime? where is the name of the file coming from?

Answer (score 1):

For instance, you can use the `join` function from `os.path` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html))

```
import os    
output_dir = "Test"

files = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]
for f in files:
    open(os.path.join(output_dir, f)) #this combines the path into Test/file1, etc. 
    #write etc here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [os.path.join(path, filename)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create the desired path.

> os.path.join('path/to','file.jpg')